# Can I read the file names of all the appsettings files in a project

Tags: c#

I have an appsettings file that has all the settings for each environment used in the application.

ie:

- appsettings.dev.usa.json
- appsettings.qa.usa.json
- appsettings.dev.eu.json
- appsettings.qa.eu.json

Each of these appsettings files have connectionstring and other configuration settings.
I have a console app that I would like generate a list of environments to display based off of the files in my project.

The console app would print out a list of environments:

- dev.usa
- qa.usa
- dev.eu
- qa.eu

Is there a way I can read the names of my appsettings files and use it in my console app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those files are designated as resource files in your project, you can get them.

In your project, click on each file.  In the properties for each file, there is an option for "Build Action".  You can set that as an "embedded resource" (among other things).

```
foreach (var x in System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames())
   Console.WriteLine(x);
```

This will dump out ALL the resources in your application.  The format will be the path down to the file based on dotted.folder.file convention.  Ex

```
YourApp.SomeSubFolder.YourAppSettings.YourJSONFile1.json
YourApp.SomeSubFolder.YourAppSettings.YourJSONFile2.json
etc.
```

To actually read the content of that file you could do by ex:

```
using (var ms = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                        .GetManifestResourceStream( "YourApp.SomeSubFolder.YourAppSettings.YourJSONFile1.json"))
{
   if (ms != null)
   {
      // if the memory stream is good, setup a stream reader to get the content
      var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
      var readContents = sr.ReadToEnd();

      // now you have a string of the json file to work with
   }
}
```